# Is there a way to put a box behind text in p5.js with the default font?

Tags: javascript, fonts, processing, p5.js, opentype

I want to make a box that tightly fits around my text in a p5.js canvas -- this can be done, but I can only figure out how to do it by loading a new font into the program.

Can creating a tight box behind text be done with the default font, thus avoiding having to load a new font?

**Further explanation**
To get a tight box around some text on a canvas, one uses the `textBounds()` method to obtain the, well, bounds of the text. You'll obtain the position of the corners of a box that fits tightly around your text. Now, in the p5.js example found at http://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Font/textBounds that I have put in a Code Snippet below, it appears that you **must** load a font with `loadFont()` before using `textBounds()` to get the bounds of the box that contains the text. My question is, how is this done without loading a font and just using the default font?

For example, I had to use an externally hosted google font for the "Code Snippet" below. **I'd rather just put a box behind the default font, to avoid having to load some font.**

```js
let font;
let textString = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.';

function preload() {
  font = loadFont('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/google/fonts/master/ofl/alikeangular/AlikeAngular-Regular.ttf');
}

function setup() {
  background(210);

  let bbox = font.textBounds(textString, 10, 30, 12);
  fill(255);
  stroke(0);
  rect(bbox.x, bbox.y, bbox.w, bbox.h);
  fill(0);
  noStroke();

  textFont(font);
  textSize(12);
  text(textString, 10, 30);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@0.9.0/lib/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have a p3 method which adds line breaks so my text doesn't exceed the tile which contains it. I'm not sure if it could help, but if you think so I can post it.

Comment: No, you do want to use an explicit font: there is no guarantee that the default font is going to look the same for different people, because p5 does not presupply it (it just relies on a font name to magically exist on people's computer, and it can't even indicate which _version_ of that font it needs to be). So if you don't want to use google fonts, host your own font (in woff2 or the older woff format, **not** ttf or otf) in the same dir as your page instead of on google, and job's done.

Comment: I've had trouble getting p5.js to use woff2, but not trouble with the older ttf/otf. Is this default behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is by design that `p5.Font.textBounds()` will have to be called after defining a font - you will see the same thing with many other methods of the p5.Font class, e.g. `textToPoints()`. There is a reason for this -

1. There is no way to retrieve the default font from a given browser using p5.js.
2. It is anyway good practice to set the font you are using for your application, since the "default" would be different for different browsers. Same would apply if you're writing a Processing program on MacOS and then run it on Windows - the default font will be automatically mapped onto the most suitable "default" font available at a given platform.

TL;DR - no, there is no way of running `textBounds()` without defining a font.

Comment: Okay, I see the reasoning. p5.js doesn't know about the font until you call it. Hypothetically, I bet the developers could make p5.js determine this if they wanted to. To me it seems to be silly to have to go through extra code, and to find a source font, to do something that should be easy.

Comment: Except concretely, they can't. JS running in a browser can't ask which version of a font it's been given, which means that as far as any JS can ever tell is that folks with Arial 3.0 and Arial v5.001 (which are quite different), are using the same font just because the name matches. Even more fun with things like San Fransisco, which is both a hilarious fantasty font (from 1984) and a clean UI font (from 2015).

Comment: As I understand it then from what you are saying, JS running in a browser doesn't load the default font on startup. If you ask it to do something with a font, and you don't ask it to use a specified font from somewhere else, it will just grab whatever the default font is and blindly use it. Why doesn't JS ask what the default font is and load the default font on startup, rather than just blindly grabbing it on the chance it is called?